# Unable to initialize UserControl with nested Dependency properties

Tags: wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I'm trying to expose two dependency properties of a nested control. In this case `Mask` and `DisplayFormatString`.

```
<UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:View.UserControls"
             xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core" x:Class="View.UserControls.DateTimeEdit"
             mc:Ignorable="d" >
    <Grid>
        <dxe:DateEdit x:Name="localDateEdit" Width="200" MaskType="DateTime" 
            ShowEditorButtons="True"
            Mask ="dd MMM yyyy HH:mm" 
            DisplayFormatString = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I've added Dependency properties to the Parent control

```
public partial class DateTimeEdit : UserControl
    {    
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayFormatStringProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayFormatString", typeof(string), typeof(DateTimeEdit), new PropertyMetadata(0));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MaskProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("Mask", typeof(string), typeof(DateTimeEdit), new PropertyMetadata(0));


        public string DisplayFormatString
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayFormatStringProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DisplayFormatStringProperty, value); }
        }

        public string Mask
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(MaskProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MaskProperty, value); }
        }

        public static void OnDisplayFormatStringChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            (d as DateTimeEdit).localDateEdit.DisplayFormatString = (string)e.NewValue;
        }

        public static void OnMaskChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            (d as DateTimeEdit).localDateEdit.Mask = (string)e.NewValue;
        }
}
```

However, when I try and set the properties on the parent control I get an exception relating to incorrect input format. `Default value type does not match type of property 'DisplayFormatString'`

UserControl usage.

```
<userControls:DateTimeEdit
          Mask="dd MMM yyyy" 
          DisplayFormatString="dd MMM yyyy"/>
```

Am I exposing the nested Dependency properties correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`PropertyMetadata(object defaultValue)` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557329(v=vs.110).aspx) uses its `object` parameter as a default value for the dependency property. Here...

```
new PropertyMetadata(0)
```

...you're passing an integer as a default value for a `String` property. That's what the exception means.

Try `null` for both properties:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayFormatStringProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayFormatString", typeof(string), 
        typeof(DateTimeEdit), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public static readonly DependencyProperty MaskProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("Mask", typeof(string), 
        typeof(DateTimeEdit), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Or `""`, if appropriate.